# Probability and real roots of a polynomial

Tags: probability, polynomials, roots

Today, I suddenly thought of a question:

> Find the probability that a $n$-degree polynomial has $r$ real roots. ($0\le r\le n$)

So, I created a function $P\left(r;n\right)$ which is the probability that a $n$-degree polynomial has $r$ real roots. Then, I try some small values.

For $n=1$, it is easy to see that $P\left(0;1\right)=0$ and $P\left(1;1\right)=1$

For $n=2$, we need to consider the determinant $\Delta$ of $x^2+ax+b$. (It has the same probability ratio as $ax^2+bx+c$)

When $\Delta \le 0$, which means $b \le \dfrac{a^2}{4}$, the probability of choosing $a,b$ with such condition is $0$, so $P\left(0;2\right)=P\left(1;2\right)=0$. Similarly, $P\left(2;2\right)=1$

Then, I have a guess: $P\left(0;n\right)=P\left(1;n\right)=\cdots=P\left(n-1;n\right)=0$ and $P\left(n;n\right)=1$. However, it consists of high-degree polynomial so I can't prove my guess. Is there anyone can help me. Tips are free, thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can start here: https://www.quora.com/Given-a-quadratic-equation-with-random-coefficients-what-is-the-probability-that-it-has-real-roots

Comment: What's the distribution of the coefficients ?

Comment: How are you picking the coefficients?

Comment: What probability distribution is used when choosing the numbers? Without that info nothing can be said. On base of what do you say that: "...the probability of choosing $a,b$ with such condition is $0$..."

Comment: I am picking the coefficients randomly

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio That doesn't mean anything. I can randomly choose the coefficients from the set $\{0,1\}$ with probabilities $0.5$ each and likely attain a different result.

Comment: Presumably by “picking the coefficients randomly” the OP means according to a uniform distribution, but clarification would be appropriate.

Comment: Keep in mind that any $n$ degree polynomial, which has $n+1$ terns, there are $n-1$ degrees of freedom. Any polynomial can be both depressed and normalized without any loss in generality in the roots.

Comment: Take a quadratic, $ax^2+bx+c=0$.  Depress it, you horizontally shift the graph and therefore the roots, and you get the equation $az^2 + C = 0$. Then normalize, you are left with $z^2 + p=0$. What is the probability of having 0, 1 or 2 real roots? Thats equivalent to the probability that $p>0$, $p=0$ and $p<0$, respectively.  If the real numbers, $p\in\mathbb{R}$, can all be chosen with a symmetric probability distribution centered at $z=0$ then $P(0)=P(2)=0.5$. While $P(1)$ is effectively zero.

Comment: There is an isomorphic mapping between the roots of the depressed monic and the roots of the generalized quadratic. Cardinalities are the same then, and which set (real or complex) is the same. 
That said, [Bertrands Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability) "Wikipedia article on Bertrands Paradox") illustrates how probability problems can have multiple solutions depending on interpretation and solution approach. Define your problem well before asking it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments you need to specify a probability distribution for this question to be meaningful. For example, here is one way of generating a random polynomial of degree $n$: let $(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ be any random vector of real numbers and consider the random polynomial
$$
p(x)=(x-Z_1)\cdots (x-Z_n).
$$
You can write out the coefficients in terms of the $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$ to see that they are truly random (except for the $x^n$ which has coefficient $1$) so it meets your criteria, and all the probabilities match your guess: $0$ probability of having $r<n$ real roots, probability $1$ of having $n$ real roots.

On the other hand, we can also consider the random polynomial
$$
q(x)=(x^2+Z_1^2+1)\cdots (x^2+Z_n^2+1)
$$
which has no real roots, and again you can multiply out the coefficients and see they are random.

Now I guess that neither of these two examples match what you are actually interested in, which is the case where all the coefficients are drawn randomly from the same distribution and independently of each other. Now the question is more interesting and has a lot of research literature that is easily accessible (for example here https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4128) and some less accessible literature going back over 50 years. While the papers may be difficult to read if you are not familiar with probability theory at the graduate level, the results are easy to summarize: in most cases people have studied, the expected number of real roots is quite a lot smaller than $n$, approximately of size $\log n$, and as a result there is a very low probability of having $n$ real roots especially as $n$ grows larger and larger. The precise asymptotic is that the expected number of real roots grows as
$$
\bigl(\tfrac{2}{\pi}+o(1)\bigr)\log n\text{ as }n\to\infty,
$$
where the notation $o(1)$ denotes a quantity that converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.